# Spring-Tiles annotation based configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles

Hi I am a newbie in Spring framework, In my application I need to integrate Spring with Tiles. How can I add `viewResolver` for Tiles as well as `internalViewResolver` for my login page, or how can I make it as one.I am using annotation based configuration. My login page location is

[image]

My config class is

```
public class AppConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}
     ........//
```

}

where should I place my Tiles JSPs. I hope my question is clear, Please comment for additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `UrlBasedViewResolver` view resolver and not the `InternalResourceViewResolver` since the suffix, view name and prefix would be specified in the Tiles Definition XML files.

```
@Bean 
public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() { 
    UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
    return viewResolver;
} 


@Bean 
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() { 
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[]{
            "/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml", 
            "/WEB-INF/defs/tiles.xml"  //another definition
    }); 
    tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
    return tilesConfigurer;
}
```

And add  in your Tiles Def XML file for each views like this:

For url path `http://localhost:8080/register`:

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
```

Definition:

```
<definition name="page" template="/WEB-INF/layout/page.jsp">
    <put-list-attribute name="stylesheets">
        <add-attribute value="/resources/css/AdminLTE.min.css" />
    </put-list-attribute>
    <put-list-attribute name="javascripts">
        <add-attribute value="/resources/js/main.js" />
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>

<definition name="register" extends="page">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="User Registeration" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/register.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="current" value="register" />
</definition>
```

I have an example on [Github](https://github.com/RawSanj/spring-tiles-sample-app) for Spring Tiles but it is using XML Configuration, you can use above @Bean Configuration to make it use JavaConfig.

Comment: one more doubt, in spring security configuration can i give .formLogin().loginPage("/register").usernameParameter("ssoId").?

Comment: There are several examples on Spring Security with java config, have a look at them. You can always ask another question if you get into issues. The github repo I shared above has spring security configured in xml, I'm sure java config won't be difficult.